# simple vector field plot - tag times protected

Tags: vector, field

I've got a problem which a lot of others seemed to have as well but I can't solve it:

I want to plot a simple Vector Field in Mathematica, in an empty, sheet, there's nothing before or after that:

```
VectorPlot[{x, y}, {x - x^3, -3, 3}, {y - y^3, -3, 3}]
```

and

```
VectorPlot[{x, y}, {x*(1 - exp[x]), -3, 3}, {y*(1 - exp[y]), -3, 3}]
```

and it says in both times: 
Tag Plus in x-x^3 is Protected
"Tag Times in x\ (1-exp[x]) is Protected. "

I've done it in two seperate, empty sheets, only trying one vector field at a time, even restarted Mathematica, and I don't know how to solve it.

I would be thankful for help
Greetings